# How to make a time series graph with PHP and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, time-series, regression

I have a mysql table containing the value of a function at different timestamps.

```
id  value timestamp
--  ----- ----------
1   1000  01.04.2014 15:50
2    995  02.04.2014 16:42
3    875  etc
4   1002  etc
5    952  03.04.2014 13:58
```

I want to plot a graph, and estimate the time when the value reaches 0.

Is there a ready to use JavaScript library (something like Excel) for this ?

I know there is [Morris.js](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/), but it only takes years as x-axis values. Not timestamps.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you heard of [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)? They have a very good API. If you need an offline solution, look at [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/).

Comment: Have you know about High Charts? http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: also, [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/), [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) might be helpful

Comment: Thanks for all the help! They look good. But one example with mysql timestamps in the x-axis and also a zero-crossing regression would be great !

Comment: morris.js takes timestamps also, read their docs. Look for other questions to see the ajax/morris interaction.